# Qt: Is QHttp's get function thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the following code:

```
class USBCamCaptureThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

void run() {
    while (!threadQuit){

            mutex.lock();
            bytes.clear();
            buffer->reset();
            Request = http->get (url->path(),buffer););
            mutex.unlock();
        MG::SLEEP::msleep(250);
    }
 }

public:
USBCamCaptureThread(){
    QFile file("setting_files/cameraIP.txt");
    QString line = "192.168.1.5:80"; //default value
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        line = in.readLine();
    } 
    file.close();
    url = new QUrl(line);
    http = new QHttp(this);
    buffer = new QBuffer(&bytes);
    threadQuit = false;
    imageReaded = true;
    open(0);
}

~USBCamCaptureThread(){
}

public slots:
void Finished(int requestId, bool error){
        QImage localImage;
        mutex.lock();
        localImage.loadFromData(bytes);
        mutex.unlock();
        QImg = localImage;


        emit signalUSBImageRead();
}

bool open(int camID){
    buffer->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    http->setHost(url->host());
    connect(http, SIGNAL(requestFinished(int, bool)),this, SLOT(Finished(int, bool)));
    return true;
}
```

Note that the *run()* is in a worker thread and the *Finished()* is in the main thread.

My question is: since the documentation says the QHttp get function is "The function does not block; instead, it returns immediately. The request is scheduled, and its execution is performed asynchronously."

Is it possible that when the *requestFinished* is emitted and *Finished()* is triggered, it happens that the *run()* function has the mutex and therefore the *QBytearray bytes.clear()* is called and when Finished() got the mutex, there is nothing to be loaded from the *QBytearray bytes*?

Furthermore, if the process of *http->get()* is scheduled to be processed later, does that mean its operation on *buffer* is no longer protected by the mutex?

Comment: I don't see any mutex in the `USBCamCaptureThread::Finished` slot. Why are you over complicating things? You could just use a [worker object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details) and have the slot run in the same thread as the `run` function.

Comment: @thuga, sorry I have fixed the code, sort of typo... by worker object, you mean to move the Finished() slot to the same thread as run()?

Comment: Check the docs I linked to, there is an example of a worker object there. Basically you just move your object to a new thread by using [`QObject::movetToThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread). And you don't subclass `QThread`, you subclass `QObject`.